# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in chrome 39 and 40 but works in chrome 36.Help fix in chrome 39

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, ssl

I am able to access a URL in Chrome 36 and IE8 but in Chrome 39 or 40 or Firefox 35 it throws the error:

> Unable to make a secure connection to the server.  This may be a
> problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
> authentication certificate that you don't have.
>
> Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR}.

It seems that it is an issue related to the SSL certificate. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

[Google announced](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) that they would begin removing support for SHA-1 cryptographic hash algorithm beginning with Chrome 39. According to Google:

> HTTPS sites whose certificate chains use SHA-1 and are valid past 1 January 2017 will no longer appear to be fully trustworthy in Chrome’s user interface.

There are several sites which can provide detailed analysis of your SSL certificate chain, such as [Qualys SSL Labs' SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Google Chrome does have a **highly risky** command-line option `--ignore-certificate-errors` which might bypass certain certificate errors. Be aware that ignoring certificate errors puts all of your SSL traffic at risk of being eavesdropped on.

It's also possible that this is a new bug. Google switched from using OpenSSL library to it's own "BoringSSL" library in Chrome 38. To report a bug in Chrome visit `chrome://help/` and click "Report an issue".

Answer (score 2):

Try this. In Chrome, enter "chrome://flags/#enable-quic" without the quotes as a URL. CTRL + F to search for "quic", at which point you'll find...

Experimental QUIC protocol. Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Enable experimental QUIC protocol support. #enable-quic

Turn that to **disabled**, and let it restart your browser when prompted below.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows Firewall, click on "Restore Defaults", then again. The problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue resolved when I turned off my Antivirus Browsing control.

Answer (score -1):

First check that in :

1. Internet Explorer- go to `tools/internet options/advanced` in the settings box, scroll all the way to the bottom and select `Use TLS 1.0` and it will fix the problem. 
   SSL 2.0 or 3.0 and these are should also be selected.
2. Google Chrome-Click "wrench" sign on the tope right of it.Click `Options` then `Under the bonnet` in network click `Change Proxy Settings` and follow the steps above as in Internet Explorer.

If this didn't work try the following steps:

1. Unhide all the files and folders.
2. Then go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
3. Right click on hosts file,then click properties. Then click security tab. After that click edit.
4. Here,click system and you have to check on allow full control and uncheck deny.
5. Click OK and then OK.
6. Now delete the hosts file.

You could read [google forum tips from  here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/gWOCNmiVtfQ/Y8iUxl6juYgJ)
or you get all the details solution [about err_ssl_protocol_error from here](http://www.toppctech.com/best-fix-err-ssl-protocol-error/). I hope this will work and fix the error.