# CORS: Accessing ssl endpoint from non ssl site

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ssl

I'm trying to access my API endpoint (https) from a http:// site.

In my PHP Application i set the header to

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

The response contains it. Nevertheless the following error occurs if i try to call the endpoint via AJAX:

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

The cert seems to be valid. Can i disable the checking somehow?
It should be safe to access SSL content from an non SSL site. Correct?

Comment: What web browser are you using? Is your website on HTTPS securely configured? If you visit the URL in your browser then do you get the same message? You can you check it on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.
When visiting in the browser I don't get any errors. The report for the domain shows a yellow B. (B for better then nothing I hope ;-)
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.romneys.de

Comment: So your issue seems to be that Chrome doesn't like something about your SSL. I would take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28037272

Comment: Did you set AJAX to use JSONP?

Comment: It seems to work in firefox. So i think you're right with your certificate guess.

Comment: One workaround would be to use your HTTP server as a proxy to fetch the HTTPS request via cURL.

Comment: I won't do that and istead fix the problem with the cert.
Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to fix your certificate issue but if that is not feasible then you can use your HTTP server as a proxy to fetch HTTPS data via PHP's cURL:

**HTTP AJAX call**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/call_api.php',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**HTTP call_api.php**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // return response as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example2.com/api_file.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200)
{
    echo $result;
}
```

**HTTPS api_file.php**

```
<?php
// some database stuff returning JSON or whatever
echo json_encode($db_rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with a not so secure certificate.
The error occured only in google chrome.